# TypeORM 0.3.10+ - what is the default poolSize

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

In TypeORM version `0.3.10` and above they added the `poolSize` property that is supported for every driver.
I am running postgres. I am interested to know what the default `poolSize` is.

I didn't see anything in the docs and in the main typeorm repo:  `https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm.git`

When I searched for `poolSize` I saw that it is optional and I didn't see a default value. Yet I assume there is a sensible default value like `10` in the previous versions but I need confirmation.

Thanks!